# TypeORM migration:generate not generating migrations

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

#### Some details:

My code is written in Typescript.

I'm using typeorm version 0.3.12

And my relevant typeorm data source file (in `src/dataSource.ts`) looks like this:

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    
    // some options here

    synchronize: false,
    entities: ["src/entity/*Table.ts"],
    migrations: ["src/migration/*.ts"],
    subscribers: [],
...
```

In short, I want my typeorm to identify new entity files as defined above, and create the corresponding migration files when I run `typeorm migration:generate` as per [the docs](https://typeorm.io/migrations#generating-migrations)

### Problem:

But my typeorm won't generate migrations based on my entity files. (Note that I already have my a data source linked to a MySQL database. And I can successfully query the db using my dataSource object.)

### Error I'm getting

When I run `typeorm -d src/dataSource.ts migration:generate -n AddIndexToListing` I get the following error:

```
typeorm migration:generate <path>
...
Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

which is not the expected behavior according to [the typeorm docs](https://typeorm.io/migrations#generating-migrations).

I then provided a value for `<path>` just to have the command run. Then it returned the following error:

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: Unable to open file: "/home/ubuntu/projects/projectA/src/dataSource.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at CommandUtils.loadDataSource (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/typeorm/commands/CommandUtils.js:22:19)
    at async Object.handler (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/typeorm/commands/MigrationGenerateCommand.js:68:26)
```

### What I tried

I did try running without specifying the data shource with -d, but it specifically asks for the data source when I do.

I also tried using `typeorm-ts-node-commonjs` instead, but that prints out other errors. (It requests for a data source. But then it complains when I pass one in using the `-d` flag, saying that I provided an invalid argument.)